# Linear regression with education as an ordinal variable

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

I wanted to know can I take education as an ordinal variable in my analysis. For example Olevels as 1, A levels as 2, Bachelors as 3, Masters as 4, PHD as 5 and then run a simple linear regression? Is this acceptable and does it make sense? To clarify education is an independent variable

Comment: Is education an outcome or explanatory variable?

Comment: Independent variable...sorry for missing that crucial detail

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ordinal+variable+regression have you browsed other questions with these keywords?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice summary of what one can do with categorical variables [at the UCLA Stats Consulting site](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/faq/coding-systems-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-analysis-2/).

Breaking it up into dummy variables is probably the most frequently used approach. Here's an answer that gets into [the interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/325957/7071).